# Attach existing Office Meeting to Outlook Calendar Event

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to attach an existing Office Meeting (Teams or Skype) to a calendar event?

It appears the Event API currently only allows [auto-generating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#create-and-enable-a-meeting-online) a meeting, by setting `isOnlineMeeting: true` and e.g. `"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"` when creating an event.

It would be helpful if you could attach an existing meeting (perhaps created by the Cloud Communications API) to a meeting, either when creating it or when updating it.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this, I am also looking for this solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe this new feature to be implemented by Microsoft then I would suggest you to consider filing Microsoft user voice - so that they can consider it. Here's the link - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=onlinemeeting